# What type (laptop or pc) of RAM do I have and will it work for me?

Tags: mac, memory

I have a PC and for some bizarre circumstances I ended up acquiring Mac series RAM (from patriot) rather than PC series RAM. I have already looked for an answer, but what I found was that as long as it isn't made for Mac, (laptop-size) it could work for a PC. I need the RAM for my PC, not a laptop, which is where the problem comes in.
Here's a picture of the package the RAM came in:
[image: picture of the package the RAM came in]
I do not know how to distinguish it from usable or not.
My question is, is it a laptop RAM? My motherboard is a P8H67-M from ASUSTek. The RAM is an 8GB PC3-12800 1600mhz (2x4) kit.

Comment: Without actually knowing what sort of mac it was (and I think most macs outside the cheesegrater macs use 'laptop' type SODIMM) this is impossible to answer. If its SODIMM, it won't fit. If its the same style of ram, with the appropriate notch, it should. Without more information this is impossible to answer.

Comment: There's no such thing as "Mac" RAM. Macs use standard [JEDEC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JEDEC_memory_standards) RAM types.

Comment: fixed it the best I could, I understand what was unclear and corrected what I saw was too vague, even provided an image for reference

Comment: [edit] and add the info from the ram sticker.

Comment: And add the details of your laptop motherboard (make/model).

Comment: Those are SODIMMS - so laptop style.  Per ASUS's site you need DDR3 1333/1066 Hz Non-ECC, Un-buffered Memory - they are about 5.5" or 6" long, compared to the 2.5" to 3" that the SODIMMS are

Comment: How do I mark it as resolved?

Comment: With VERY few exceptions, unless you're some uber-geek looking to build the ultimate machine or have a very narrow and specific set of specifications you're looking for, the ONLY thing you need to consider about your RAM is fit. There are two aspects to RAM fit: the size of the stick and the location of the notch(es) in the line of connectors. You could have answered this question yourself by looking inside your computer and observing the very apparent difference in size between the sticks you acquired and the sticks installed. THAT is the answer you're looking for.